# Non-converging integral that should be 0

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, substitution, wolfram-alpha

A question requires you to prove that $$\int_0^\infty f(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{a}{x})\frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx=\ln{a}\int_0^\infty f(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{a}{x})\frac{1}{x}dx...........(1)$$

I made the substitution x=at, and split the resulting logarithm $\ln{at}$ in the integral into two, and got the above left-hand integral to be $$\ln{a}\int_0^\infty f(t+\frac{1}{t})\frac{1}{t}dt+\int_0^\infty f( t+\frac{1}{t})\frac{\ln{t}}{t}dt.......... (2)$$
Now, when you substitute back the variables in the first term above, you get the valie on the right in equation 1. So the second term in integral 2 must be 0.

But I can't integrate that second term, and when I ran that term on WolframAlpha, it came out as 0 for $f(x)=sin(x)$, but it doesn't even converge for $f(x)=cot(x)$ or $log(x)$.

So I've messed up somewhere there. Can someone help me with where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set $g(t) := f\left(t+ \frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{\ln(t) }{t}$
you can split the second term in (2) as
$$
\int_0^1 g(t)\,dt+ \int_1^{\infty} g(t)\,dt
$$

and observe that $\int_0^1 g\left(t\right)\,dt =-\int_1^{\infty} g(t)\,dt $
using the substitution $x=\frac{1}{t}$. 
(Here, $\int_0^1g(t)\,dt=\int_{\infty}^1 g(\frac{1}{t})\,d(\frac{1}{t})=\int_{\infty}^1f(t+\frac{1}{t})t (-\ln{t}).\frac{-1}{t^2}\,dt=-\int_1^{\infty}g(t)\,dt$).
Thus, summing up the two integrals you obtain $0$.

I think in the last two attempts you made the integral is not convergent, hence the two terms above are both infinite and the proof is no more true.
You should add the convergence of the integral in your hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that told me immediately what I needed to know! But can you elaborate on how the split integrals cancel out? I can sort of see how $x, \frac{1}{x}, \ln{x}$, and $x$ all change roughly symmetrically to cancel out, but I can't get it rigorously proved. Also, why doesn't the integral converge in the last two cases? Your derivation works for every function, as far as I can see.

Comment: You have $g(x)=g(1/t)=f(t+1/t)t\ln(1/t)=-f(t+1/t)t\ln(t)$ and the differential is $dx=-1/t^2\,dt$. Now you substitute and theintegral becomes $\int_{\infty}^1 g(t)\,dt=-\int_1^{\infty} g(t)\,dt$.

Comment: The proof is wrong if the integral is divergent, you obtain an indeterminate form of type $\infty-\infty$

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't work for *all* functions, you've gotta check if it's convergent, is that so? I haven't really learnt about the convergence of integrals yet- can I assume these intricacies will be dealt with there?

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x=\frac{a^2}t$
\begin{align}
I=& \int_0^\infty f(\frac{x}{a}+\frac{a}{x})\frac{\ln{x}}{x}dx\\
= &\int_0^\infty f(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{a}{t})\frac{\ln{a^2}-\ln t}{t}dt\\
= &2\ln{a}\int_0^\infty f(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{a}{t})\frac{1}{t}dt-I\\
= &\ln{a}\int_0^\infty f(\frac{t}{a}+\frac{a}{t})\frac{1}{t}dt
\end{align}